# AOP programming - ProceedingJoinPoint is only supported for around advice

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am having this exception while deploying my new aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(PreAuthorizeAccess)")
    public Object tessst(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        for (Object object : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
            int a = 0;
        }
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ProceedingJoinPoint is only
>   supported for around advice   at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.maybeBindProceedingJoinPoint(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:414)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.calculateArgumentBindings(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:388)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]

I want to intercept all methods annotated with `@PreAuthorizeAccess` and change something in myObject, like this:

```
@PreAuthorizeAccess
public MyObject save(@Param("argument") MyObject myObject) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring AOP provides multiple pieces of advice, `Before` and `Around` among others. You have inadvertently combined the two by setting up a `@Before` advice and retrieving the method arguments passed to the advice using a `ProceedingJoinPoint`, which is reserved for the use of an `@Around` advice. Hence the exception.

From the Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html):

> Before advice: Advice that executes before a join point,
>       **but which does not have the ability to prevent execution flow proceeding
>   to the join point (unless it throws an exception)**.
>
> Around advice: Advice that surrounds a join point such as a method invocation. This is the most powerful kind of advice. Around advice can perform custom behavior before and after the method invocation. **It is also responsible for choosing whether to proceed to the join point** or to shortcut the advised method execution by returning its own return value or throwing an exception.

Either declare a before advice using:

```java
@Before("@annotation(PreAuthorizeAccess)")
public void tessst(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    for (Object object : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
        int a = 0;
    }
}
```

Or wrap the method invocation in an `@Around` advice using `@Around("@annotation(PreAuthorizeAccess)")` instead of `@Before("@annotation(PreAuthorizeAccess)")`.

Although based on the snippets you have provided, my guess is that a `@Before` advice might be more suitable in your situation.

Comment: Besides, if you cannot remember which is which: Only from an `@Around` advice you can (optionally) `proceed()` to the original method call, from `@Before`/`@After` advices you do not have that option as `@Before` cannot avoid execution in another way than throwing an exception and for `@After` it makes no sense because the method has already finished execution. **Update:** My comment happened pretty much simultaneously with the answer edit quoting from the Spring manual, explaining basically the same thing.